# Split command line arguments into string array --- Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, command-line-arguments

I am new to Java and still getting used to object-oriented programming (C Programmer).

Command line arguments: AB5, BC4, CD8, DC8, DE6, AD5, CE2, EB3, AE7

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    String[] edges = args[0].split("[, ]"); 

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        System.out.println(edges[i]);
}
```

What I think it does:

It is supposed to split the first argument into a string array using spaces and commas as delimiters. I wanted to print out to see if it was working but then I got this message after it prints out "AB7":

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 on line 8

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use split. Command line arguments arrive in an array, as they are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below code. Command line arguments are already separated by spaces so you dont need to pass any comma delimited string and call split.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        String[] edges = args;//args[0].split("[, ]"); 

        for(int i = 0; i < edges.length; i++)
            System.out.println(edges[i]);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the individual command line arguments in args. But, if your user insists on writing commas as a decoration:

```
public static void main(String[] args){   
   String[] edges = String.join( " ", args ).split("[, ]"); 
   for(int i = 0; i < edges.length; i++)
      System.out.println(edges[i]);
   }
}
```

This will also get rid of the commas, if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you need to this as follows

1) Create a pattern for you regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ ,]") ;
```

2) Now you need to match it against you input

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
```

3) you can print as follows

```
while(matcher.find()){
     System.out.println(String.format("found match of %s at %d and %d ",  matcher.group(), matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
 }

// sample code
public static void main(String[] args){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String arg: args){
        sb.append(arg);
    }

    Matcher matches = Pattern.compile("[ ,]").matcher(sb);
    while(matches.find()){
        System.out.println(String.format("found match of %s at %d and %d ",    matches.group(), matches.start(), matches.end()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

It's a actually splitting on all commas and spaces. "[, ]" is a regular expression. You're getting that exception because you've exceeded the length of the edges array.

Rather than hardcoding in 9, you should use the length of the array in your loop invariant instead to avoid this issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    String[] edges = args[0].split("[, ]"); 

    for(int i = 0; i < edges.length; i++)
        System.out.println(edges[i]);
}
```

In your example though, the arguments are actually already split at the spaces and stored into the args array.

You can forget the comma and just pass the arguments in as:

`AB5 BC4 CD8 DC8 DE6 AD5 CE2 EB3 AE7`

And then iterate over them like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        System.out.println(args[i]);
}
```